# Error posting comments using Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, django-rest-framework

My aim is to post a comment to a particular post id using Facebook graph API.

This is the code snippet for the same:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/<post_id>/comments'
parameters = {'access_token': <FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN>, 'message': 'test comment'}
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
parameters = json.dumps(parameters)

response = requests.post(url, data=parameters, headers=headers, timeout=10)
```

I am calling this API inside my DJANGO POST API.

For Some Reason, Calling the Facebook API through this code doesnt work. The API call gets timeout after 10 seconds.

If I call the Facebook API through Postman / YARC , the comment gets posted successfully.

Can any one tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Python Requests example:**

import requests

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/yourPostId/comments"

querystring = {"access_token":"yourtoken"}

payload = "message=test%20comment"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)

---

**Python http.client example:**

import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("graph.facebook.com")

payload = "message=test%20comment"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/v2.11/yourPostId/comments?access_token=yourtoken", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more useful and clear for future users :)

Comment: I did an app for java, and I use Graph API. Here is my code: https://github.com/OswaldoRosalesA/FacebookAPIJava.git

Comment: @DaFois thank you, here is an more useful answer. I hope it works.

Comment: @OswaldoRosales I tried both of your codes, but still the issue is not solved. The call gets timeout after 10 secs.

Comment: Did you change the post id?